# How to use cin inside a function?

Tags: c++, function

I am new to c++ and am trying to make a simple text based game. The code below is supposed
to welcome the user to the game and ask whether or not the user wants to start the game. I don't get any build errors, but when I run it all it shows is a blank screen. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
string D1(string Original)
{
    cin >> Original;
    return Original;
}

int main ()
{
    string Decision1;
    cout << "Welcome to [game name]" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to start the game?" << endl;
    cout << "Yes/No" << endl;
    string D1(Decision1);
    system("cls");
    if (Decision1 == "Yes")
    {
        cout << "this happens" << endl;
    }
    else if (Decision1 == "No")
    {
        cout << "that happens" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you know you can format your code? Indent with 4 spaces per indentation (no tabs!) and this will be much easier to read.

Comment: `string D1(Decision1);` is not how you call a function. You probably should start with a book on C++...

Comment: D1() should not take an argument.

Comment: Let me strongly recommend a book such as __Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++__. It will explain all of this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 7):

You have to call `D1`, not create a new variable named `D1`:

```
std::string D1()
{
    std::string Original;
    std::cin >> Original;
    return Original;
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to [game name]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Would you like to start the game?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Yes/No" << std::endl;
    auto Decision1 = D1();
    system("cls");
    if (Decision1 == "Yes")
    {
        std::cout << "this happens" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (Decision1 == "No")
    {
        std::cout << "that happens" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`string D1(string Original)` should be `string D1(string& Original)` (ie: passing with reference)

and

`string D1(Decision1);` in `main` should be

`D1(Decision1);` because

`string D1(Decision1);` actually declares a new string variable, called `D1` (same name as the function) and initializes it with the value of `Decision1`

Answer (score 3):

This statement

```
string D1(Decision1);
```

is a definitiom of an object of type `std::string` with name `D1` that initialized by object `Decision1`. As the object `Decision1` is empty then and object D1 is empty.

What you meant is the following

```
void D1( string &Original )
{
    cin >> Original;
}

//...

D1( Decision1 );
```

or the following

```
string D1()
{
    string Original;
    cin >> Original;
    return Original;
}

//...

Decision1 = D1();
```

Take into account that if you use two if statements

```
if (Decision1 == "Yes")
{
    cout << "this happens" << endl;
}
else if (Decision1 == "No")
{
    cout << "that happens" << endl;
}
```

then you have to add a third statement with `else` because the user can enter neither "Yes" nor "No". Also you should compare strings independently of their case (upper case or lower case). So you have to convert strings to some common case.

For example

```
#include <cctype>

//...

for ( char &c : Decision1 ) c = std::toupper( c );
if ( Decision1 == "YES" )
{
    cout << "this happens" << endl;
}
else if ( Decision1 == "NO" )
{
    cout << "that happens" << endl;
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

P.S. And here in comments there was suggested book "Programming -- Principles and Practice Using   C++. " I do not advice this book for beginners. In fact it is a bad book for beginners. You will spend much time reading the book but your knowledge of C++ will be close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
string D1(string Original)
```

Right now, the program will make a copy of the string you pass and place it into `Original`, so when you come out of the function, nothing will have happened to `Decision1`.

What you want it to do is [***pass the variable by reference***](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

Passing a variable by reference means the function isn't receiving a copy of what was passed, but the actual variable you passed (imagine a voodoo doll). Anything you do to the variable in the function will take effect on the variable passed.

Change the function header to:

```
string D1(string &Original)
```

Comment: Changed the function header to string D1(string &Original) and it still comes up with a blank screen